# Importing and inheriting class from h-file. "Base class undefined"

Tags: c++

I am working on a small project with three classes. But my code won't compile. These classes are *PacketObject2*, *PacketList2* and *PacketInt2*.

The code won't compile with the error `'PacketObject2': base class undefined` in both `PacketInt2.h` and `PacketList2.h`.

PacketObject2.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

#include "PacketList2.h";

using namespace std;

class PacketObject2
{
public:
    virtual void Print();

    virtual int CompareTo(PacketObject2 other);

    virtual PacketList2 ToList();

    virtual bool IsOpen();

    virtual void AddInt(int value);

    virtual void OpenChild();

    virtual void CloseChild();

};
```

PacketObject does not have a cpp-file.

PacketList2.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "PacketObject2.h"
#include "PacketInt2.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PacketList2 : public PacketObject2
{
private:
    vector<PacketObject2> objectsInList;
    bool isOpen;
public:

    PacketList2();
    PacketList2(PacketInt2 pi);

    PacketList2 ToList();

    void Print();

    int CompareTo(PacketObject2 other);

    void AddInt(int value);

    bool IsOpen();

    bool HasOpenChild();

    void OpenChild();

    void CloseChild();
};
```

PacketList2.cpp:

```
#include "PacketList2.h"
#include "PacketObject2.h"
#include "PacketInt2.h"


vector<PacketObject2> objectsInList;
bool isOpen = true;

PacketList2::PacketList2() {

}
PacketList2::PacketList2(PacketInt2 pi) {
    objectsInList.push_back(pi);
}

PacketList2 PacketList2::ToList() {
        return *this;
    }

void PacketList2::Print() {
    cout << '[';
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsInList.size(); i++) {
        objectsInList[i].Print();
        cout << ',';
    }
}

int PacketList2::CompareTo(PacketObject2 other) {
    PacketList2 otherList = other.ToList();
    for (int i = 0;
        i < min(objectsInList.size(), otherList.objectsInList.size());
        i++) {
        int comparison = objectsInList[i].CompareTo(otherList.objectsInList[i]);
        if (comparison != 0) {
            return comparison;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void PacketList2::AddInt(int value) {
    if (objectsInList.back().IsOpen()) {
        objectsInList.back().AddInt(value);
    }
    else {
        PacketInt2 pi(value);
        objectsInList.push_back(pi);
    }
}

bool PacketList2::IsOpen() {
    return isOpen;
}

bool PacketList2::HasOpenChild() {
    return objectsInList.back().IsOpen();
}

void PacketList2::OpenChild() {
    if (HasOpenChild()) {
        objectsInList.back().OpenChild();
    }
    else {
        PacketList2 pl;
        objectsInList.push_back(pl);
    }
}

void PacketList2::CloseChild() {
    if (HasOpenChild()) {
        objectsInList.back().CloseChild();
    }
    else {
        isOpen = false;
    }
}
```

PacketInt2.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "PacketList2.h"
#include "PacketObject2.h"

using namespace std;

class PacketInt2 : public PacketObject2
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    PacketInt2(int value);

    void Print();

    PacketList2 ToList();

    int CompareTo(PacketObject2 other);
};
```

PacketInt2.cpp:

```
#include "PacketInt2.h"
#include "PacketList2.h"

int value;

PacketInt2::PacketInt2(int value) {
    this->value = value;
}

void PacketInt2::Print() {
    cout << value;
}

PacketList2 PacketInt2::ToList() {
    PacketList2 pl(*this);
    return pl;
}

int PacketInt2::CompareTo(PacketObject2 other) {
    PacketInt2* otherPtr = dynamic_cast<PacketInt2*>(&other);
    if (otherPtr == nullptr) {
        return ToList().CompareTo(other);
    }
    if (otherPtr->value == value) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (value < otherPtr->value) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (value > otherPtr->value) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I think I have done something with the imports that doesn't work. I am very new to the concept of h-files. Can you guys help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: You're cross-including the two headers. Pick an order.

Comment: The error mentions the base class, which occurs well before the method declarations. This should be a clue that you could probably greatly simplify your [mre] for this question. It suggests that details after specifying the base class might be droppable. Try dropping the class methods, simplifying the definition of `PacketList2` to just `class PacketList2 : public PacketObject2 {};`. Then compile to make sure the issue is still reproduced. Then repeat for `PacketInt2`.

Comment: `PacketList2.h` includes `PacketObject2.h` which in turn includes `PacketList2.h`. Think very carefully what will happen when the compiler reads those header files (especially in light of `#pragma once`). The error should make sense then, The solution is not to have two header files including each other. Use forward declarations and/or out-of-class method definitions to break the cycle.

Comment: See [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/) (possibly not a duplicate because it does not use a base class, but the principles are similar).

Comment: Please ask yourself why `PacketObject2.h` includes `PacketList2.h` and not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite like this

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class PacketList2; // forward declaration

class PacketObject2
{
public:
    virtual void Print();
    virtual int CompareTo(PacketObject2 other);
    virtual PacketList2 ToList();
    virtual bool IsOpen();
    virtual void AddInt(int value);
    virtual void OpenChild();
    virtual void CloseChild();

};
```

The *forward declaration* of `PacketList2` allows you to remove the inclusion of `"PacketList2.h"` which breaks the cycle of header file includes.

I've also removed `using namespace std;` which is bad practice at the best of times but a sackable offense when placed in a header file.

Also, not what you asked about, but this is wrong

```
int PacketInt2::CompareTo(PacketObject2 other) {
    PacketInt2* otherPtr = dynamic_cast<PacketInt2*>(&other);
```

Should perhaps be this

```
int PacketInt2::CompareTo(PacketObject* other) {
    PacketInt2* otherPtr = dynamic_cast<PacketInt2*>(other);
```

or maybe this

```
int PacketInt2::CompareTo(const PacketObject& other) const {
    const PacketInt2* otherPtr = dynamic_cast<const PacketInt2*>(&other);
```

In your version `other` has lost it's polymorphic nature so the `dynamic_cast` is guaranteed to fail. In C++ polymorphism only works on pointers and references (like both of my suggestions). This issue is known as *object slicing* which you might want to research.

I'm getting former Java programmer vibes.

Comment: Spot on, I come from Java background and trying to learn c++. Thanks for help!